# Story where a young mans stays up with a corpse which revives in the morning

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Hi I am looking for a short story that is about a teen who is trying to make it back home but is short of cash. He calls his parents and tells them  his situation. A lady offers to let him stay at her house for the night under one condition; he must watch over her dead husband. In the end the dead man comes alive and tells the town that the wife murdered him. I remember this short story was in a short story compilation but I cannot remember the name of the story or the book!